# How to set machine hostname as docker container hostname

Tags: linux, docker

I want to set the docker container hostname to the machine hostname on which docker is installed. Please note than I want to set the hostname dynamically and don't want to hardcode the machine hostname in my `docker run` command.
How do I achieve this?

My docker run command:

```
sudo docker run --name=rabbitmq -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 \
-e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin \
-e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin \
--hostname ?? \
-v rmq_vol:/var/lib/rabbitmq \
rabbitmq:3.9.0
```

Comment: soo `--hostname "$(hostname)"`?

Answer (score 0):

What KamilCuk said.

add to docker run:  --hostname $(hostname)

You're just passing in the result of the linux "hostname" command to your docker run configuration.